# Understanding Addition inference Rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, natural-deduction

Studying *Discrete Structures, Logic, And Computability by James L. Hein*, came across this proof.

On line 3, the author uses that rule to get $A v B$. Two questions arose:

1. Is it possible to introduce a variable that was not mentioned in the Premises ? What would be the reasoning behind that ?
2. Is it possible to introduce a variable that was mentioned in the Premises with the opposite truth value (negated if it wasn't or vice versa) ?

[image: Example 6]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to introduce a variable that was not mentioned in the Premises ? What would be the reasoning behind that ?

Yes.   If $A$ holds in the context, then you may infer that $A\vee B$ holds (whether $B$ does or does not).   After all, $A\vee B$ is the claim that *at least one* from $A$ or $B$ holds.   So *when* at least one does (eg $A$), then the disjunction holds too.

**PS**: the rule of Addition is not about adding the *whole statement*.   In logic proof systems, it refers to the rule by which any *disjunct* can be added to an existing statement.   That if $A$ is derivable (or assumed), then $A\vee B$ may be inferred in the same context.

> 2. Is it possible to introduce a variable that was mentioned in the Premises with the opposite truth value (negated if it wasn't or vice versa) ?

It is possible to raise an assumption (rule **P**) that contradicts a prior statement.   You may open a sub-proof by assuming anything as needed for the sake of argument; just be sure to close the sub-proof by discharging it with a valid rule (such as rule **CP**, "conditional proof").

This is the **Principle of Explosion**, otherwise known as *ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet* (Latin for "from falsehood, anything follows").   If your premises contain a contradiction, you *can* derive *anything* via valid rules of derivation.   Since it *is valid* to do so, therefore you *may* do so.

---

So you want to prove $\neg A\to(A\to B)$?  Well, since that is a *conditional statement*, you should use a *conditional proof*: raise $\neg A$ as an assumption with the aim to derive $A\to B$.

So you want to prove $A\to B$, under the assumption of $\neg A$? Well, again you should use a *conditional proof*: raise $A$ as an assumption with the aim to derive $B$.

So you want to prove $B$ under the assumptions of $\neg A$ and $A$? Well, you have assumed $A$ so you may infer $A\vee B$ (via Addition), but you have also assumed $\neg A$, so you may further infer $B$ (via **D**isjunctive **S**yllogism).

Why now, you have successfully derived $B$ in the context of the two assumptions, $\neg A$ and $A$, so you may now discharge those assumptions to close the two conditional proofs.

Thus you have proven $\neg A\to(A\to B)$ using the rules of *assumption*, *conditional proof*, *addition*, and *disjunctive syllogism*.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  If A is true, then A or B is absolutely true.  A or ~B is true.  A or (B and ~B) is true!

Why would you do this?  Well, like in your sample proof that a false antecedent implies any consequent, you would need to add B somehow.  Or if you had to prove $(A \vee B) \implies (C \vee D)$ given $A \implies C$ and $B \implies D$.  You can do a proof by cases, but you need to turn $A \implies C$ to $A \implies (C \vee D)$ to generate the proof.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer already explains the other points quite well, so let me just address the remaining question,

> What would be the reasoning behind [introducing another variable, possibly one that does not occur among the premises]?

At first sight, the disjunction introduction might indeed seem not very useful: If we already know that A holds, why would we weaken and complicate that knowledge by turning it into "A *or* B"?

First of all, let's observe that such a disjunction introduction is *sound*: Suppose we have derived or are given as a premise the sentence "The gardener is the murderer", and we apply Add with a new sentence to arrive at the statement "The gardener is the murderer or Lady Smith's cat is grey". Then with the knowledge we have, if someone asks "Is at least one out of the claims true that the gardener is the murderer or Lady Smith's cat is grey?", then we can faithfully answer "yes". The addition of the second alternative does not invalidate our previous knowledge of A, it merely weakens it.

So what is the point of doing this?

While the addition of the second disjunct in the above example was indeed not very useful, in some situations it is. Suppose we know that the local swimming pool has an outdoor pool, which is always accessible from June until August, and in addition it is opened when it is more than 25°C outside. We can formalize this fact as a statement of the form

> $(A \lor B) \to C$

where $A$ represents the proposition "It is between June and August, "B" stands for "It is more than 25°C", and $C$ is the consequent "The outside pool is open".

Now suppose it is an exceptionally warm May afternoon with 28°C outside and we want to know if we can get into the outside pool. With the knowledge we are given, we only have the premises that 1. $(A \lor B) \to C$ (The outdoor pool is open if it is between June and August or above 25°C). and 2. $B$ (It is above 25°C). From these two formulas alone, we can not draw any conclusions:

> 1. (It is between June and August $\lor$ It is more than 25°C outside) $\to$ The outside pool is open
> 2. It is more than 25°C outside
>      ...?
> 3. The outside pool is open

Now the disjunction introduction comes in handy: By adding a second disjunct to the premise $B$ -- which we are allowed to do either to the left or the right, as $A \lor B$ is equivalent to $B \lor A$ -- we can arrive at the form of the antecedent of the implication that is necessary to derive the conclusion C, thereby completing the derivation:

> 1. (It is between June and August $\lor$ It is more than 25°C outside) $\to$ The outside pool is open
> 2. It is more than 25°C outside
> 3. It is between June and August $\lor$ It is more than 25°C outside $\quad \quad$ 2, Add
> 4. The outside pool is open  $\hspace{6.5cm}$ 1, 3, MP

(where "MP" stands for "modus ponens", in natural deduction more often written as $\to E$, "implication eliminiation"., applied to the implication $(A \lor B) \to C$ on line 1 and antecedent $A \lor B$ on line 4.)

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. That was one of the things I was trying to understand. On line 3, you added “It is between June and August”. You added a second disjunt that is exactly the same as one of the propositions mentioned in the premise. Can I say it is possible to add a proposition despite it was mentioned or not? In this case, I could get: _It’s cold in Mars $\vee$ It is more than 25°C outside_, but couldn’t use MP to derive the conclusion. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "You added a second disjunct that is exactly the same as one of the propositions mentioned in the premise." The disjunct you're probably talking about is proposition $A$ ("It is between June and August"), but we do *not* have that exact proposition among our premises. We only have $A$ as a *subformula* occurring in the premise $(A \lor B) \to C$. These are not the same thing -- having $A$ in the premises would mean we know (or assume) that it's between June and August, but that's not the case.

Comment: Nevertheless, it makes no difference whether the disjunct we add is a premise, occurs as a subformula in one of the premises or is a completely new proposition - we are always allowed to introduce whatever statement we want in a disjunction, if that answers your question. That statement may, by the way, also be complex (i.e. may itself involve whatever connectives rather than just a single propositional variable). So as you say, we could legitimately conclude "It's cold in March or it's more than 25°C outside", just that this step won't be any useful for our derivation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You're right, it's a sub formula. One question: when you say we are allowed to introduce whatever statement we want in a disjuntion, I presume that I cannot introduce one of the formulas appearing in the premises negated. For example: Given A, B; I can't have as one of my statements B v ¬ A. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, we can -- "anything" really means "anything", even if it contradicts the premises. We could even disjoin the existing statement with $\bot$. This won't render the proof contradictory, as we don't claim that the negated premise or $\bot$ actually holds - all we say with a disjuncts is that *at least one* out of the disjuncts holds, which is justified because because one of them was already established; and even if the new disjunct contradicts one of the premises or a valid logical principle, then we didn't lose anything, we just didn't gain any new information, ...

Comment: ... because we just introduced an alternative that is not possible anyway, so we're left with what we already knew before: As you can easily  verify with a truth table, $A \lor \bot$ -- that is, disjoining a proposition with something contradictory -- is just equivalent to $A$. If we know (or assume) $A$ to be true, then $A \lor B$ will also be true, whatever the form of $B$.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. One last question: if in the Given I have $P$, I cannot introduce $¬P$ as an  _assumption_ because I cannot contradict any of the Premises. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97538/discussion-between-lemontree-and-f-zer).